# What's the translation of score line in French?

Tags: traduction, santé-et-médecine

https://twitter.com/drmirmushtak/status/1580581360066232320:

> [image]

The lines we see on the two pills are [called](https://health.clevelandclinic.org/cutting-pills-in-half) score lines.

What's the translation of score line in French? [Google Translate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5cye.png) and Linguee weren't helpful. Google Translate suggests "ligne de score" but I don't see it being used on Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'adjectif dans le domaine c'est *sécable*, par exemple « comprimé sécable à rainures en croix » (*cross-scored tablet*) ([Vitrine](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/18961010/comprime-secable-a-rainures-en-croix)/[Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=alt&srchtxt=COMPRIME%20SECABLE%20RAINURES%20CROIX)). Donc la propriété c'est la [*sécabilité*](https://books.openedition.org/pucl/1675?lang=en) semble-t-il et à en croire les [monographies](https://base-donnees-publique.medicaments.gouv.fr/affichageDoc.php?specid=67219535&typedoc=N) de produits, on parle de « ligne de sécabilité » ; on parle aussi de « [rainures de sécabilité](https://ch.oddb.org/fr/gcc/print/reg/43216/seq/03/pack/066/patinfo/) ».

Comment: "Rainure" tout court pour traduire line dans ce cas, me semble-t-il?